# Rails 3.1 find a particular file in a Gem install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to fix a GEM that is Linux specific... it uses the which command to find a shell file installed by the GEM to call an executable and then consume the results.

I thought I could use Find.find(dir) to get the location of the file. Unfortunately searching the path for this file is cumbersome. I am looking either for a suggestion of how I can narrow the search area or a different method for finding the file.

Here is the code I am implementing right now:

```
@path_array = ENV['Path'].split(";")

require 'find'
@path_array.each do |dir|
  Find.find(dir) do |path|
    if File.basename(path) == "wkhtmltoimage-proxy"
      Rails.logger.debug("@@@ Here")
      @meow = path
    end
  end
end
```

Update...

Tried adding in a FileTest.directory? next but that seemed to bypass the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why was I searching the Path? If it is in the Path then the execution should find it. Duh.

However, the only reasonable solution I heard should I still need something like this was to request the developer to put a path in a resource file (e.g. Properties) and grab the location from there rather than use Find.

It may be why the original developer went with a `which <exe>`.chomp command since the Linux which command was much faster.